# Phonebrowser.dll (Nokia PC Suite) functions

Tags: file, api, mobile, dll, nokia

Nokia PC suite comes with a dll known as phonebrowser.dll which allows users to browse , copy and paste and exchange files between the connected mobile and pc.
I want to know list of functions (especially to copy and paste files) with their parameters that is contained in phonebrowser.dll.
Please help me and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `Dependency Walker` to find the DLL entry points.  But I am not aware of anything that can give you the parameters.  Have you tried Nokia's website

Comment: Yes I searched Nokia's website but there is no clue :(